# python 3 regex slash with Square Brackets

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to find emoji in Python 3, and I print my string is `\ud83d\ude0a`
And I can found it by
`re.compile(r'(\\ud83d\\ude0a)')`
But when I want to use Square Brackets to find like `\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]`
I write this `re.compile(r'(\\ud83d([\\ude00-\\ude4f]))');`
but just mapping `ude0a` in `\ud83d\ude0a`.

my entire code

```
str = '\\ud83d\\ude0a'
print(str)
emoji_pattern = re.compile(r'(\\ud83d([\\ude00-\\ude4f]))');
# emoji_pattern = re.compile(r'(\\ud83d\\ude0a)');
print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', str))
```

Comment: please clarify what the error is, it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you use square brackets.
Square brackets are used for selecting a single char from the chars in the brackets. Therefor, when you wrote `[\\ude00-\\ude4f]`, it will be translated to only one char in there (for example, `\\`, `u`, `d`, `0`, etc.), and not as you wanted it to be, from `\ud83d\ude00` to `\ud83d\ude4f`.

To fix this, try using `(\\ud83d(\\ude[0-4][0-9a-f]))`. It will find the sequence of the chars `\ud83d\ude` and then char in the range of `0` to `4` and then one in the sequence of `0` to `9` or `a` to `f`. As a result, this will detect the wanted sequence, and can be inspect [here](https://regex101.com/r/3fa2aw/1).